# Pandas: parsing values in structured non tabular text

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with a format like this:

```
k1[a-token]
v1
v2
k2[a-token]
v1'
k3[a-token]
v1"
v2"
v3"
```

What is the most pandorable way of reading these data into a dataframe of this form:

```
        A       B
0       k1      v1
1       k1      v2
2       k2      v1'
3       k3      v1"
4       k3      v2"
5       k3      v3"
```

that does not involve manual looping? alternatively is there any other library that allows me to input only some regular expressions that would specify the structure of my text file and output the data in the tabular form described above?

Comment: It's not clear what your format is.  Do you have some token in square brackets at the start of each group, or is your `[a-token]` just a marker that you put in here on SO to indicate the start of each group?

Comment: yeah meant to say that there is a pattern indicating end of the string for the key values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***setup***
borrowing from @jezrael

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
k1[a-token]
v1
v2
k2[a-token]
v1'
k3[a-token]
v1"
v2"
v3"
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="|", names=['B'])
print (df)
```

---

- `str.extract` with parameters specified in the regex and look ahead
- use `duplicated` to identify the rows we want to keep.

---

```
df = df.B.str.extract('(?P<A>.*(?=\[a-token\]))?(?P<B>.*)', expand=True).ffill()
df[df.duplicated(subset=['A'])].reset_index(drop=True)

    A    B
0  k1   v1
1  k1   v2
2  k2  v1'
3  k3  v1"
4  k3  v2"
5  k3  v3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with some separator which is not in data like `|` or `¥`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
k1[a-token]
v1
v2
k2[a-token]
v1'
k3[a-token]
v1"
v2"
v3"
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="|", names=['B'])
print (df)
             B
0  k1[a-token]
1           v1
2           v2
3  k2[a-token]
4          v1'
5  k3[a-token]
6          v1"
7          v2"
8          v3"
```

Then [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column `A` with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) values with `[a-token]` and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for remove rows with `keys` in `values` column:

```
df.insert(0, 'A', df['B'].str.extract('(.*)\[a-token\]', expand=False).ffill())
df = df[df['A'].duplicated()].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    A    B
0  k1   v1
1  k1   v2
2  k2  v1'
3  k3  v1"
4  k3  v2"
5  k3  v3"
```

But if file have duplicated `keys`:

```
print (df)
              B
0   k1[a-token]
1            v1
2            v2
3   k2[a-token]
4           v1'
5   k3[a-token]
6           v1"
7           v2"
8           v3"
9   k2[a-token]
10          v1'

df.insert(0, 'A', df['B'].str.extract('(.*)\[a-token\]', expand=False).ffill())
df = df[df['A'].duplicated()].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    A            B
0  k1           v1
1  k1           v2
2  k2          v1'
3  k3          v1"
4  k3          v2"
5  k3          v3"
6  k2  k2[a-token]
7  k2          v1'
```

Then is necessary change `mask` to:

```
df.insert(0, 'A', df['B'].str.extract('(.*)\[a-token\]', expand=False).ffill())
df = df[~df['B'].str.contains('\[a-token]')].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    A    B
0  k1   v1
1  k1   v2
2  k2  v1'
3  k3  v1"
4  k3  v2"
5  k3  v3"
6  k2  v1'
```

Answer (score 0):

With your file as 'temp.txt'...

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.txt',
                 header=None,
                 delim_whitespace=True,
                 names=['data'])

bins = df.data.str.endswith('[a-token]')

idx_bins = df[bins][:]
idx_bins.data = idx_bins.data.str.rstrip(to_strip='[a-token]')
idx_vals = df[~bins][:]

a = pd.DataFrame(idx_bins.index.values, columns=['a'])
b = pd.DataFrame(idx_vals.index.values, columns=['b'])

merge_df = pd.merge_asof(b, a, left_on='b', right_on='a')
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': idx_bins.data.loc[list(merge_df.a)].values, 
                       'B': idx_vals.data.values})
```

Comment: the whole point was not to have any visible loops in the code! :)

Comment: sorry about that @ShS, I didn't read your question properly.  how does this look after replacing the loop with merge_asof?